Parsing JSON without any conversions in Ruby
I am writing a Ruby script to migrate JSON files from one format to another. In this, I need to preserve the exact contents and formatting of all the values. Is there a JSON library in Ruby that will parse a file without any value validation or conversion, just leaving them as strings?
The default JSON library converts all numbers to Float, often losing precision. OJ can parse to BigDecimal, but then prints all the numbers in scientific notation. Neither lets me just skip conversion altogether.

Could you please give an example how you lose precision when default JSON library converts numbers to Float?
I might be mistaken but I thought that you lose precision when you perform arithmetic operations on floats, not when you convert string values to Float

@GProst There is a Github ticket for this: https://github.com/flori/json/issues/219 If you parse "222.95816040039063" and then dump it, you will get "222.95816040039062" back (note the last digit).

You could call JSON#load with a Proc that coerces things that look like floats to BigDecimal or String objects, which should preserve your precision.

If you're just concerned with parsing decimal numbers, there is a decimal_class option.  You could use this to choose a different class like BigDecimal or to provide your own parser:
string = "{\"num\":222.95816040039063}"

JSON.parse(string)
 => {"num"=>222.95816040039062}

JSON.parse(string, decimal_class: BigDecimal)
 => {"num"=>0.22295816040039063e3}

class NoConversion
  def initialize(raw)
    @raw = raw
  end
end
JSON.parse(string, decimal_class: NoConversion)
 => {"num"=>#<NoConversion:0x0000000110509a90 @raw="222.95816040039063">}

And as @Stefan has pointed out, you can define a to_json method to generate JSON from the custom decimal class:
class NoConversion
  def initialize(raw)
    @raw = raw
  end

  def to_json(*)
    @raw
  end
end

hash = JSON.parse(string, decimal_class: NoConversion)
 => {"num"=>#<NoConversion:0x0000000110511fd8 @raw="222.95816040039063">}

JSON.generate(hash)
 => "{\"num\":222.95816040039063}"


You can add def to_json(*) = @raw in order to generate JSON from the custom class.

This is just what I need. Thanks!
